# Calling Ktor client from java - checked exceptions

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, ktor, ktor-client

I'm currently developing/using a library which uses Ktor HTTP client to expose common functions for calling other services.

The thing is I'm calling this library from Java and I know Ktor calls (eg.: `httpClient.post(...)`) may throw some exceptions that are checked in Java.

The easy approach is to annotate all my functions with [`@Throws`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/) and specify which checked exceptions the function may throw (where [Kotlin does not care about checked exceptions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions)).

Instead of this I wanted to understand if it would make sense to use a response exception handler ([ref](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-core/io.ktor.client.plugins/-http-call-validator/-config/index.html#1007054276%2FFunctions%2F-1897681819)) and wrap all checked exceptions into `RuntimeException`s.

Something like the following:

```kotlin
val httpClient = HttpClient {
    install(HttpCallValidator) {
        handleResponseExceptionWithRequest { ex, _ ->
            if(ex !is RuntimeException) throw RuntimeException(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing if you just don't do anything?

Comment: I think the solution with wrapping into the `RuntimeException` is fine as long as you can access an original exception.